# sqlite to mysql migration issue

Tags: mysql, sqlite

mysql db query issue

SELECT B.CODE || D.QUANTITY FROM DETAILS D, PRODUCTS P, PARTIDAS B, SHOPS S WHERE D.SHOP_ID = S.ID and D.PARTIDA_ID = B.ID and D.PRODUCT_ID = P.ID and S.CODE='1' and P.CODE='pendrive' and DOCUMENT_ID=97;

returned   A1 in resultset 
its worked on sqllite

mysql  resultd got like  1
why its so what wrong

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. Probably you have done something wrong, but it is impossible to provide help if you don't explain what exactly you do.

Comment: I have added index in this customer entity like above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with using SELECT CONCAT( B.CODE, D.QUANTITY )  it work